# Android Bound Service in other thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have two Bounded Services, and some Activities that bind themselves to the services when they need it.

The problem is the performance of the app is slow when the activities write the information got from the services in the display.

Android's documentation says about the Stated Services:

> Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in
>   which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by
>   default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations
>   while the user interacts with an activity from the same application,
>   the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting
>   application performance, you should start a new thread inside the
>   service.

But it says nothing about the Bound Services running in other threads. So i decided to start the services in this way:

```
private void startRunService()
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, RunService.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    private void startLinkerRunService()
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LinkerRunService.class);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
```

So starting each service in a different service I got an unexpected improvement of the performance. But I'm not sure that it is a good idea.

Do you know if it has side effects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that running service in a random thread can crash your system :) It just doesn't look good. When you want a new thread you have to start it "INSIDE of the service in onStartCommand method". When your services extend IntentService no new threads are needed.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your answer. I wrote an _unexpected improvement of performance_ because the system was not crashed. Anyway, I created a thread inside the service in `onStartCommand` method, and a get the same performance, or even a little bit worser performance.